# How to find DNS A record of azure static website?

Tags: azure, dns

I have a static website running in Azure blob storage. I have created a CDN Profile and a CDN endpoint. I have bought a domain in GoDaddy. I am trying the configure the DNS settings and I am not sure what to give in the DNS A record. Please, can somebody help?

My static website: https://akshayastorage.z30.web.core.windows.net/
My CDN endpoint: https://akshayacdn.azureedge.net

My GoDaddy DNS mapping

CNAME   akshaya.org.in  akshayacdn.azureedge.net    1 Hour
CNAME   cdnverify   akshayacdn.azureedge.net    1 Hour

Comment: If you need to find the IP address of the static website, you can directly use `nslookup` or `ping akshayastorage.z30.web.core.windows.net` in the CMD. Is this what you want?

Comment: Nancy, if I ping that it gives me a different ip. It seems like, azure doesn't give a static IP address to the static website in azure blob storage.i am wondering is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly `ping akshayastorage.z30.web.core.windows.net` to get the IP address of your static website in Azure blob storage. You can upvote [this feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/11220711-please-implement-static-ip-address-or-reserved-ip) as providing static or reserved IP addresses for storage accounts is on Azure backlog.

As a workaround, you can host your website on an Azure VM with a static IP address. It works like a traditional on-premise machine but migrates your infrastructure on the Azure platform. Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/paths/deploy-a-website-with-azure-virtual-machines/) for more details.